# Why do my nav bars duplicate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website is 1 page full of different section divs. I have 1 nav on the home page and then after scrolling passed that another fixed nav fades in.

**Sometimes** when I scroll up there is a duplication of navs. So the fixed nav is within the normal nav. This is odd because the fixed nav should have disappeared before the normal nav reappeared.

Does anyone have any insight into this? I am using Google Chrome to display code. Could it a chrome issue?

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {    

    if($(this).scrollTop() > $('.nav').outerHeight()){
        $('.nav').hide();
        $('.nav_fixed').fadeIn("slow");
    }

    else if($(this).scrollTop() == $('.nav').position().top) {  
        $('.nav_fixed').hide();
        $('.nav').fadeIn(700);
    }

    else {

    }
});
```

Comment: can you show your markup / html?

Comment: you can try adding [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) before `.fadeIn` so you don't trigger the animation multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"This is odd because the fixed nav should have disappeared before the normal nav reappeared."*

This could be related to the fact that animations are asynchronous. Just because you have your `fadeIn()` instruction after the `hide()` instruction doesn't mean that `fadeIn()` will happen AFTER `hide()` finishes. Is is actually possible that `fadeIn()` will happen BEFORE `hide()` because of the asynchronous nature of the animations.

Try adding the `fadeIn()` to a completion callback function for `hide()` as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {    

  if($(this).scrollTop() > $('.nav').outerHeight()){

    // By encapsulating the instruction for fadeIn() inside of a 
    // function that is then passed as a completion callback to 
    // the hide() method, we ensure that fadeIn() doesn't happen
    // until hide() is finished
    $('.nav').hide(function(){
        $('.nav_fixed').fadeIn("slow");
    });   
  } else if($(this).scrollTop() == $('.nav').position().top) {

    // By encapsulating the instruction for fadeIn() inside of a 
    // function that is then passed as a completion callback to 
    // the hide() method, we ensure that fadeIn() doesn't happen
    // until hide() is finished  
    $('.nav_fixed').hide(function(){
      $('.nav').fadeIn(700);
    });      
  } else {

  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it added a slide effect. Kept sliding to the left not too sure why!

Comment: Since the hide is allowed to finish before the fade, any content that follows the hidden nav will move to fill that space. This can be addressed by putting both navs inside of a div that has a set size.